# Как закрыть модальное окно при повторном нажатии?

Tags: javascript, jquery, всплывающее-окно, окно

Доброго дня и ночи! Прошу помощи! Есть скрипт модального окна. При нажатии на блок `.open` открывается модальное окно с блоком `.modal`. При нажатии на блок `.close` модальное окно закрывается. Помогите, пожалуйста в следующем: как при повторном нажатии на блок `.open` также закрывать модальное окно?

```
$(function () {
    $('.open').click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $(".modal").addClass("show");
        }, 2500);
    });
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.modal').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".modal").hasClass("show")` - Проверяем есть ли класс `show` если есть то мы убираем его, если его нету то добавляем его.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.open').click(function(){
        if ($(".modal").hasClass("show")) {
        $('.modal').removeClass('show');
        }
        else
        {
        $(".modal").addClass("show");
        }

    });
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.modal').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: @LADYX Вы лучше добавьте этот код к себе в код и там проверьте его работоспособность. Ибо для данного кода нет на этой странице модального окна который необходимо открыть)

Answer (score 0):

можно и так с помощью
[toggle jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)